# Video downloader not working, I think it might my server

Tags: java, html, css

I am a college student, i am also working on other projects just to learn, I am working on a self made simple youtube video downloader as a website, i have a HTML, CSS, and 2 js files, one a server. Everything seems to be good but i keep getting a post related error.

Tried to change the post and fetch, But i keep getting (404 a Method not  allowed.)

https://github.com/gts170017/RYvideodownloader

```js
function isValidDownloadLocation(location) {
  // Check if the location starts with a valid protocol (http, https, file)
  if (location.startsWith('http://') || location.startsWith('https://') || location.startsWith('file://')) {
    return true;
  }

  // Check if the location is a valid file path with backslashes or forward slashes
  return location.includes('\\') || location.includes('/');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Login functionality
  const loginForm = document.querySelector('#login-form');
  const loginError = document.querySelector('#login-error');
  const loginScreen = document.querySelector('#login-screen');
  const mainScreen = document.querySelector('#main-screen');

  if (loginForm && loginError && loginScreen && mainScreen) {
    loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const username = document.getElementById('username');
      const password = document.getElementById('password');

      if (username && password) {
        if (username.value.toLowerCase() === 'a' && password.value.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
          loginScreen.style.display = 'none';
          mainScreen.style.display = 'block';
          loadState();
        } else {
          loginError.textContent = 'Invalid username or password. Please try again.';
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Username or password input not found on the page');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Required login elements not found on the page');
  }

  // Download functionality
  const videoLinkInput = document.getElementById('video-link');
  const downloadBtn = document.querySelector('#download-btn');
  const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  const statusLabel = document.getElementById('status-label');

  if (videoLinkInput && downloadBtn) {
    downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const videoUrl = videoLinkInput.value.trim();

      if (videoUrl) {
        // Make an AJAX request to the server-side API to initiate the download
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/download', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              // Handle the response from the server
              if (data.success) {
                // Update the UI based on the server's response (progress, status, etc.)
                if (progressBar) {
                  progressBar.style.width = '0%';
                  // Simulating progress update
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    progressBar.style.width = '50%';
                  }, 1000);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    progressBar.style.width = '100%';
                    if (statusLabel) {
                      statusLabel.textContent = 'Download completed successfully!';
                    }
                    addThumbnail(videoUrl);
                  }, 2000);
                } else {
                  console.error('Progress bar element not found on the page');
                }
              } else {
                if (statusLabel) {
                  statusLabel.textContent = data.error;
                } else {
                  console.error('Status label element not found on the page');
                }
              }
            } else {
              console.error('Error:', xhr.status);
              if (statusLabel) {
                statusLabel.textContent = 'An error occurred. Please try again.';
              } else {
                console.error('Status label element not found on the page');
              }
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ videoUrl }));
      } else {
        if (statusLabel) {
          statusLabel.textContent = 'Please enter a valid video URL.';
        } else {
          console.error('Status label element not found on the page');
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Video link input or download button not found on the page');
  }

  // Thumbnail functionality
  function removeThumbnail(event) {
    const thumbnailElement = event.target.closest('.thumbnail');
    if (thumbnailElement) {
      thumbnailElement.remove();
      // Remove the corresponding video info from the storage or database
      const videoUrl = thumbnailElement.dataset.videoUrl;
      // Remove the video URL from the storage or database
      // Example placeholder code:
      console.log('Removing thumbnail for video:', videoUrl);
    }
  }

  function openVideo(event) {
    const thumbnailElement = event.target.closest('.thumbnail');
    if (thumbnailElement) {
      const videoUrl = thumbnailElement.dataset.videoUrl;
      // Open the video using the appropriate method (e.g., embed video player, provide download link)
      // Example placeholder code:
      console.log('Opening video:', videoUrl);
    }
  }

  function addThumbnail(videoUrl) {
    const thumbnailGrid = document.getElementById('thumbnail-grid');
    if (thumbnailGrid) {
      const thumbnailElement = document.createElement('div');
      thumbnailElement.classList.add('thumbnail');
      thumbnailElement.dataset.videoUrl = videoUrl;
      thumbnailElement.innerHTML = `
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail">
        <div class="overlay">
          <button onclick="openVideo(event)">Play</button>
          <button onclick="removeThumbnail(event)">Remove</button>
        </div>
      `;
      thumbnailGrid.appendChild(thumbnailElement);
    } else {
      console.error('Thumbnail grid element not found on the page');
    }
  }

  // State management
  function loadState() {
    // Retrieve the saved state from the server-side storage or database
    // Update the UI based on the retrieved state
    // Example placeholder code:
    console.log('Loading application state');
  }

  // Initialize the application
  loadState();
});
```

```css
/* Reset default browser styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#app {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

h1, h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #c90000;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #b2d101;
}

#login-error {
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#status-label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#thumbnail-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.thumbnail .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.thumbnail:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.thumbnail .overlay button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Video Downloader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Login Screen -->
    <div id="login-screen">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form id="login-form">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" required>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <p id="login-error"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Main App Screen -->
    <div id="main-screen" style="display: none;">
      <h1>Video Downloader</h1>
      <div>
        <label for="video-link">Put in your Video link:</label>
        <input type="text" id="video-link" placeholder="Enter video URL">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="download-location">Download Location:</label>
        <input type="text" id="download-location" placeholder="Enter download location">
      </div>
      <button id="download-btn">Attempt to download</button>
      <div id="progress-bar"></div>
      <p id="status-label"></p>

      <!-- Video Thumbnail Grid -->
      <div id="thumbnail-grid"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="java.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
import express from 'express';
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors';
import { google } from 'googleapis';

const app = express();

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

// Initialize the YouTube Data API client
const youtube = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: 'AIzaSyDb312gEgoZT7XM2gazmiCtaKM55SPs8Sc' });

app.post('/download', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { videoUrl } = req.body;

    if (!ytdl.validateURL(videoUrl)) {
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: 'Invalid video URL' });
    }

    // Get video information using the YouTube Data API
    const videoInfo = await youtube.videos.list({
      part: 'snippet,contentDetails',
      id: ytdl.getVideoID(videoUrl),
    });

    const videoTitle = videoInfo.data.items[0].snippet.title.replace(/[/\\?%*:|"<>]/g, '-');
    const videoFileName = `${videoTitle}.mp4`;
    const downloadDir = path.join(__dirname, 'downloads');

    // Create the downloads directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(downloadDir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(downloadDir, { recursive: true });
    }

    const filePath = path.join(downloadDir, videoFileName);

    // Download the video
    const videoStream = ytdl(videoUrl, { quality: 'highest' });
    videoStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
      .on('finish', () => {
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Video downloaded successfully', filePath });
      })
      .on('error', error => {
        console.error('Error downloading video:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to download video' });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting video info:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to get video information' });
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hey Damian could you provide the fetch API code because it seems there might be error there

Comment: Yes, Of course.

Comment: Ensure that you use the `POST` method where it is necessary and other methods accordingly because the error that you are getting `Method not allowed` states that you're using the wrong method type.

Comment: Are you sure it will be `POST` method?

Comment: Also its preferable to use `Axios` library when using fetch API functionality to make it easier, when using NextJS

Comment: Why is this tagged java?